# EPPlus: ExcelChartSerie.Header loads once but doesn't update when cell is changed

Tags: c#, excel, graph, epplus, epplus-4

I am trying to create an EPPlus chart.  I am having problems with series headers.  Even when ExcelChartSerie.HeaderAddress is used, it seems to have no effect.

Each serie is initialized with the following piece of code

```
ExcelBarChartSerie serie = (OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.ExcelBarChartSerie)
                           chartClustered.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(fromRow, fromCol, toRow, toCol),
                                                     ExcelRange.GetAddress(fromRow, fromColH, toRow, fromColH));

ExcelAddressBase headerAddr = new ExcelAddressBase(headRow, headCol, headRow, headCol);
serie.HeaderAddress = headerAddr;
serie.Header = (string)ws.Cells[headRow, headCol].Value;
```

Everything works great but I am having problems with the Header updating correctly with the rest of the graph.  The serie.Header variable controls the legend, which is where I'm having the problem.  I  understand this is an awkwardly specific question, but perhaps someone out there can offer some insight.  Here is some pictures to show you exactly where I am having my problem.

Initial plot before a change (correct):
[image: before]

Plot after label data changed (incorrect):
[image]

Comment: Note that I have tried to use serie.HeaderAddress without using serie.Header but to no avail (the program creates a blank legend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the you are creating a new Excel Address that is NOT attached to a worksheet when setting `HeaderAddress`.  Its a very subtle but important difference because Excel would not know which sheet the address is actually associated with when looking for the header value (it would not assume the one the chart is on).  Take a look at this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExcelChartSerie_Header()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866521/epplus-excelchartserie-header-loads-once-but-doesnt-update-when-cell-is-change
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add("newsheet");

        //Some data
        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Stuff";
        ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "bar1";ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "bar2";ws.Cells["A4"].Value = "bar3";ws.Cells["A5"].Value = "bar4";ws.Cells["A6"].Value = "bar5";

        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Canadian";
        ws.Cells["C2"].Value = 53;ws.Cells["C3"].Value = 36;ws.Cells["C4"].Value = 43;ws.Cells["C5"].Value = 86;ws.Cells["C6"].Value = 86;

        ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Saudi Arabia";
        ws.Cells["D2"].Value = 53;ws.Cells["D3"].Value = 36;ws.Cells["D4"].Value = 43;ws.Cells["D5"].Value = 86;ws.Cells["D6"].Value = 86;

        ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Alaskan";
        ws.Cells["E2"].Value = 53; ws.Cells["E3"].Value = 36; ws.Cells["E4"].Value = 43; ws.Cells["E5"].Value = 86; ws.Cells["E6"].Value = 86;

        ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "Indian";
        ws.Cells["F2"].Value = 53; ws.Cells["F3"].Value = 36; ws.Cells["F4"].Value = 43; ws.Cells["F5"].Value = 86; ws.Cells["F6"].Value = 86;


        //Create the chart
        var chart = (ExcelBarChart)ws.Drawings.AddChart("Chart1", eChartType.ColumnClustered);
        chart.SetSize(400, 300);
        chart.SetPosition(10, 400);

        //Apply header
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var serie = (ExcelBarChartSerie) chart.Series.Add(
                ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(2, i + 3, 6, i + 3),
                ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(2, 1, 6, 1)
            );

            //var headerAddr = new ExcelAddressBase("C1");  //THIS IS NOT ASSOCIATED WITH WORKSHET 'ws'
            var headerAddr = ws.Cells[1, i + 3]; //THIS IS
            serie.HeaderAddress = headerAddr;
            //serie.Header = (string) ws.Cells[1, i + 3].Value;
        }
        package.Save();

    }
}
```

Comment: A am still having trouble with this.   I just tested it and I am still getting a blank legend

Comment: @jnel899  Did the test method above work for you?  I think you would need to paste all of your code for people to properly troubleshoot.

Comment: I just tested your code in isolation and it definitely works.  The mistake must be on my end somewhere, I'm looking for it now.

Comment: @jnel899  Ok cool.  If you get stuck just edit your question and paste it in - never hurts to have another pair of eyes.

Comment: Ok, I got your answer to work on mine as well.  Thanks for the help!  The problem was I was trying to further manipulate the Header string (to prevent it from being too long). It doesn't look like I'll be able to do this anymore but its not a big deal, I'd rather have this functionality working